# SQL distinct with group by in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I have following SQL:

```
select 
  origin,destination,to_char(to_date(substr(ship_date,1,6),'YYMMDD'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD'),ship_date,trip_number, distinct ship_number  
from shipment a 
where 
  a.scc_code in ('xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx') 
  and load_status = 'S' and ship_date like '11%' 
  and shipper_id = XXXXXX
group by origin,destination,ship_date,trip_number, ship_number
```

When I run this SQL in Oracle it gives ORA-00936: missing expression.  If I remove the distinct keyword, it runs fine.  Can anybody tell me the difference between those two things?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are already grouping by all these columns, including ship_number, so it will be already distinct.

Comment: Distinct keyword should apply to all selected columns..

Comment: Thanks i realize the place where i gone wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Distinct keyword is for all selected columns, so you have to put it before select

```
select distinct 
  origin,destination,to_char(to_date(substr(ship_date,1,6),'YYMMDD'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD'),ship_date,trip_number, ship_number  
from shipment a 
where 
  a.scc_code in ('xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx') 
  and load_status = 'S' and ship_date like '11%' 
  and shipper_id = XXXXXX
group by origin,destination,ship_date,trip_number, ship_number
```

Comment: yes.i realize that error that i did.when add distinct key word to all selected columns it works.Thanks for all.

Comment: If this the correct answer to your question, it would be polite to mark it as such.